# how to merge to a local branch after checking out to a previous commit

Tags: git, merge, commit

I am working on a local branch `VISS`. Then I decided to check out a previous commit:

> git checkout 98ea3c8042c39e

I made some important changes to the code. and then I committed again.

Now I need to go back to my branch `VISS` keeping these changes.

What should I do if I want to:

1. Go back to my `VISS` branch discarding what was done before checking out to a previous commit (`98ea3c8042c39e`).
2. Go back to my `VISS` branch merging the new changes with what I had done on the top of the `VISS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go back to your branch and discard everything :

   ```
   git checkout VISS
   ```

   Your new commit atop `98ea3c` will be left floating in the middle of nowhere, and will eventually be garbage collected by git.

   Conversely, if you are willing to make `98ea3c` the top of `VISS` and discard what `VISS` is currently pointing to, do the following:

   ```
   git checkout VISS
   git reset --hard 98ea3c
   ```
2. Go back to `VISS` and merge your new changes on the top of it:

   ```
   # On the new commit you just made:
   git rebase VISS

   # Now take note of what the commit ID is.  Assume I got "abc123"; then:
   git checkout VISS
   git merge abc123
   ```

   You'll now have `VISS` with the change as the latest commit, and no merge commit.

Comment: Item 2 solves one of my question but as with the first question, Actually I want to keep my important changes which were made AFTER the roll back and discard VISS. I mean suppose I started from point A, then commited to reach point B and then again to Point C (this is my current VISS). Then I switched backwards to commit B, made some changes to reach a point(say D). Now i want git to ignore B-to-C development and make VISS to point to D...  is this possible?

Comment: Of course. Checkout `VISS`, and then issue `git reset --hard D` (where `D` is the ID of that commit). Now `VISS` points to `D`.

Comment: thanks Len, I am marking it as correct answer. perhapse you reflect the above comment to your answer to remove any confusion(if any).tanx again

Comment: @rahman: done! Accepted your edit (and reformatted slightly). :) Glad I could help.